Cannot find docker/podman executable
I would like to bother you, I am trying to create a container in docker desktop on macOs, but even though the docker-compose.yml file is correct, when I run the command sudo docker compose up -d It generates the error:
  => ERROR [app-api publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish -c release --no-restore -o /app -r linux-x64 --self-contained false --no-build 40.4s
------
  > [app-api publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish -c release --no-restore -o /app -r linux-x64 --self-contained false --no-build:
1.744 MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
14.09 AppApi -> /app/
17.33 Building image 'appapi' with tags 'latest' on top of base image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0'.
39.72 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/Containers/build/Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers.targets(210,5): error: Cannot find docker/podman executable. [/src/AppApi/AppApi.csproj]
39.72 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204/Containers/build/Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers.targets(210,5): error CONTAINER1012: The local registry is not available, but pushing to a local registry was requested. [/src/AppApi/AppApi.csproj]
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c release --no-restore -o /app -r linux-x64 --self-contained false --no-build" did not complete successfully: exit code : 1

It is a .net core 8 project but it seems to me that the error is somehow being generated in docker (v4.24.2 (124339))

You shouldn't need to use sudo just docker compose up -d

thanks, I run with sudo and without sudo and the error persists.

I managed to discover the cause of the problem with the help of this other post:
Getting Container Error while publishing inside docker file
What was causing the problem was a property declared in my main solution .csproj file, the property is:
<PublishProfile>Default container</PublishProfile>

Eliminating this property solves the problem.
